# Basic algebra exercise solver

Tags: math, nlp, calculator

I am looking for a program that can solve basic algebra exercises [such as](http://www.testprepreview.com/modules/algebra1.htm):

> - If Lynn can type a page in p minutes, what piece of the page can she do in 5 minutes?
> - If Sally can paint a house in 4 hours, and John can paint the same house in 6 hour, how long will it take for both of them to paint the house together?
> - Employees of a discount appliance store receive an additional 20% off of the lowest price on an item. If an employee purchases a dishwasher during a 15% off sale, how much will he pay if the dishwasher originally cost $450?
> - The sales price of a car is $12,590, which is 20% off the original price. What is the original price?
> - Solve the following equation for A : 2A/3 = 8 + 4A
> - If Leah is 6 years older than Sue, and John is 5 years older than Leah, and the total of their ages is 41. Then how old is Sue?

I would prefer if it runs on Windows or Linux.

Comment: You mean software that can parse the English sentences, extract the equations and solve them? Try Wolfram Alpha… in a couple of decades.

Comment: @Gilles Wolfram Omega!

Comment: @unor Adding typos back to the post:)

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, as these are quotes, the source would have to correct them first before we should ;)

Comment: @unor I know, just giving you a hard time:D

Answer (score 4):

Some of the questions you posted can be solved by linear simultaneous equations technique.
[Sequalator](http://sequalator.blogspot.com/p/features.html) is a software which can solve linear simultaneous equations for you.
It can not only tackle thousands of equations in a fraction of a second but also provides some unique tools that let you analyse the solutions of your equations.
And the best part is that it is free!

**[DISCLOSURE]** - I am the developer of Sequalator.

**EDIT 1:** Sequalator will not read the text form of questions. You have to understand the question and then translate it into a suitable system of equations. You can then enter the coefficients of these equations and let Sequalator do the remaining job for you!

**EDIT 2:** You can watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9O3FW6DygY) short video to get introduced to Sequalator within 10 mins.
This should help get you started very quickly and easily.